# SwiftUI: PreferenceKey Reduce method never gets called

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to pass data up a view chain using Preferences but .onPreferenceChange is never called. Investigating a bit reveals that while the Debugger shows execution passes through my
.Preference modifier, the reduce method is never called to push the new value into the key. I can not figure out why, nor can I find a way to examine the View's Preference key:value data.

here is the code:

```
struct LittleTapPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = String
    static var defaultValue: Value = "A0"
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> String) {
        print("Inside Little Reduce \(value)and NextVal =  \(nextValue())")
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

here is cell View where on tap of a GlyphCell instance in a QGrid, the Pref modifier is set:

```
struct GlyphCell: View {

    var glyph:Glyph
    @State private var selected = false   // << track own selection

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("\(glyph.Hieroglyph)")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(.all, 12.0)
                .font(.system(size: 40.0))
                .background(Color.yellow)
            Text("\(glyph.Gardiner)")
                .offset(x: 12, y: 28)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.onTapGesture {
            print("Tap on \(self.glyph.Gardiner)")
            self.selected.toggle()
        }
        .cornerRadius(6.0)
        .frame(width: 90.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        .background(Group {
            if self.selected {
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: LittleTapPrefKey.self, value: self.glyph.Gardiner)
            } // end selected test
        }   // end  group
      )     // end .background
    }       // end cell body view
}
```

with a Breakpoint set on the .pref(key:...), the breakpoint triggers every time a cell is tapped, and the value of self.glyph.Gardiner is correct at that point.

Breakpoints or the test Print statement in the Preference Key Struct "reduce" function are never triggered. Since the .onPrefChange is never triggered, I have to assume the Value never gets changed, but I have no way to directly view the Pref value.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The `reduce` is called when you set one preference key in one view hierarchy several times, so SwiftUI gives you possibility to combine them somehow, eg:

```swift
.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
.preference(key: LittleTapPrefKey.self, value: value1) // 1st time
.background(Group {
    if self.selected {
        Color.clear
            .preference(key: LittleTapPrefKey.self, value: value2) // 2nd time
    }
}
```

in your case you have only one value setter, so it is just set and `.onPreferenceChange(LittleTapPrefKey.self)` callback modifier works as expected.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: I knew the function of the reduce, but did not know how smart it was in terms of triggering the update to the stored key location.  In my case the set key statement in the self.selected block appears to execute, and the glyph was correct, but no callback.   You suggest a "first call" to preference key with (garbage) value, then set the key with desired value. So it changes the setting twice in a call to the cell view.   I dont understand why it should require two settings, but you have been right on with your other suggestions so I will try it this morning!  Again thanks Asperi!!!!

Comment: @BlueskyMed, it was not a suggestion, but demo of the case when reduce would work. Of course you should not set pref twice.

Comment: Ah!  Nonetheless, after the initial round of setting of the QGrid, the callback in the parent is never called after a select Cell.  This is a curious anomaly to track down! I added an onPrefChange to the parent view of the QGrid parent and it also does not trigger.  The interesting thing is, now that the reduce is triggered, the NextVal in the print statement is always the "garbage" value from the added setPref, and never the vaue from inside the isSelected block!

Comment: I added a debugger PO stmt inside the reduce, and see that for each tap, reduce is called more than 20 times!  First with correct values, then with defaults! Back to the drawing board!

Comment: sorry but your explanation of the reduce function is too vague for me.